# Pandas access a specific value from a dictionary of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I've a dataframe that have a dictionary with this format (the column name is 'due'):

```
{'date': '2020-05-21', 'is_recurring': False, 'lang': 'en', 'string': 'May 21', 'timezone': None}
None
```

I was trying to get the item 'date' with the following code:

```
print(df.due.apply(lambda x: x['date']))
```

But I was getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

So I was trying to convert the None to NA in order to avoid this error (is the best practice?). For that I am using this:

```
df['due'] = np.where(df['due'] is None, np.nan, df['due'])
```

However, the None rows continue to appear as None. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have NaNs in your column:

```
df
                                                 due
0  {'date': '2020-05-21', 'is_recurring': False, ...
1                                                NaN
```

In this case pandas offers `str.get` (or `.str[..]` shorthand) as a "safe" way for indexing objects:

```
df['due'].str['date']

0    2020-05-21
1           NaN
Name: due, dtype: object
```